# How to set bus on apple's AudioUnit 3D Mixer?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, audio, audiounit

I'm trying to figure out how to query or setup which sound is connected to which bus input of the 3D Mixer. Say I have an explosion sound, is there a way to specifically set which bus that sound will be located on for future reference?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working with an `AUGraph()`, this is pretty straightforward: 
Just connect the node to the desired busNumber of the mixer.

```
// connect the file player's output to the mixer's input
checkResult( AUGraphConnectNodeInput(audioGraph,
                                     filePlayerNode,
                                     0,
                                     mixerNode,
                                     1, // this is the first bus #1 "AUGraphConnectNodeInput(filePlayer:out -> mixer:in");
```